# No profiles for 'com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner' were found

Tags: xcode, facebook, appium, appium-ios

So I am trying to move my tests over to start using the new XCUITest Driver, when I follow the documentation to install the WebDriverAgentRunner I am having issues that appear to be related to the code signing. I have searched and not finding anyone with the same issue so far, so I am reaching out for a bit of guidance on what I am doing wrong.

I have followed all the steps in this document - https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/README.md

It appears to be successful when I run this on a simulator, however when running this on a REAL device, it gives me issues.

This is the output when I run

> xcodebuild -project WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme
>   WebDriverAgentRunner -destination
>   'id=ae69b635db6e40c3f7719eb8f81c24e200028564' test

Output ->

```
=== BUILD TARGET WebDriverAgentRunner OF PROJECT WebDriverAgent WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies
The file “ProjectSettings.xcconfig” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/Configurations/ProjectSettings.xcconfig)
No profiles for 'com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner' were found:  Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 'com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner'.
Code signing is required for product type 'UI Testing Bundle' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'
No profiles for 'com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner' were found:  Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 'com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner'.
Code signing is required for product type 'UI Testing Bundle' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'
No profiles for 'com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner' were found:  Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 'com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner'.
2016-10-19 09:15:07.930 xcodebuild[98516:8284369] Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=3 "Test operation was canceled. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /Users/trent/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-gvltwgknevnwclanwpylmjozekma/Logs/Test/880BC4BB-80AD-4D0B-8D9A-52368970AEB8/Session-WebDriverAgentRunner-2016-10-19_091503-rg0a32.log" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Test operation was canceled. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /Users/trent/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-gvltwgknevnwclanwpylmjozekma/Logs/Test/880BC4BB-80AD-4D0B-8D9A-52368970AEB8/Session-WebDriverAgentRunner-2016-10-19_091503-rg0a32.log}
Code signing is required for product type 'UI Testing Bundle' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'
Code signing is required for product type 'UI Testing Bundle' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'


Testing failed:
    No profiles for 'com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner' were found:  Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 'com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner'.
    Code signing is required for product type 'UI Testing Bundle' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'
** TEST FAILED **
```

Comment: well this has been an issue for me for last one week. havent been able to find any solution. please post if you get any issues in the coming days.

Comment: @Trent check this out : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySglJIrDVMQ

Comment: Have a look at this.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262570/unable-to-launch-ipa-file-in-ios-10-real-device-using-appium-1-6-0/40521535?noredirect=1#comment68292922_40521535