# Can't run Appium tests on iOS 10 on real device

Tags: java, ios, xcode, appium

Since updating my device and xCode to iOS 10 and Xcode 8, I have been unable to successfully setup Appium testing on a real device. However, I works fine on the simulator. Below is my setup of capabilities:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

    File f = new File("/Path/App.ipa");

    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APPIUM_VERSION, "1.6.0");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "iOS");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "10.1.1");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone 6 (Model MG472B/A)");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "20a548dc87a87ecddf7ab3975a4b5f3395ac1a0");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP,f.getAbsolutePath());
    cap.setCapability("bundleId", "co.uk.xx");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME,"XCUITest");
    cap.setCapability("noReset", "true");

    try {
        driver = new IOSDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);   
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm faced with the error below:

'An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unknown device or simulator UDID: 'xx'.

Appium Log via link https://gist.github.com/dodigital/ee5944f31b34749edf3d1c57146594e7

Comment: check this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySglJIrDVMQ

Comment: @Manidroid thank you for the suggestion. I have followed the instructions on the video and also built the WebDriverAgent project but still can't run tests on a Real device. The error mention above still persists

Comment: post full appium log

Comment: @Manidroid updated with the log

Comment: Can u try by removing udid. Because you are running in simulator no need of UDID as you are giving device name,ios version. Remove tha capability for app also because we cannot install .ipa file through appium.We can install it manually and give bundleid

Comment: I want to run on a real device hence I had the device's UDID there

Comment: Available devices: 20a548dc87a87ecddf7ab3975a4b5f3395ac1a0b
[XCUITest] Error: Unknown device or simulator UDID: '20a548dc87a87ecddf7ab3975a4b5f3395ac1a0' . This is the error you are getting you are giving wrong udid. you are missing 'b' in the end

Comment: hat was exactly the issue, can't believe I missed that, thanks

Comment: cool, next time please post with your appium logs, so that it will be easy for us to debug it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Available devices: 20a548dc87a87ecddf7ab3975a4b5f3395ac1a0b [XCUITest]    Error: Unknown device or simulator UDID: '20a548dc87a87ecddf7ab3975a4b5f3395ac1a0' .
```

This is the error you are getting you are giving wrong udid. you are missing 'b' in the end

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to resolve the issues and run on a real device with the following steps:

- I had omitted the last character in the UDID, added 'b' as suggested above.
- Added the xcodeConfigFile and realDeviceLogger to the list of capabilities.
- Ensured the correct development teams where set up on the WebDriverAgent.

Anyone having issues, please feel free to write underneath this post. I spent two good days figuring things out the hard way.