# Signing for "WebDriverAgentRunner" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor

Tags: ios, xcode, appium

Is it mandatory to provide development team in the xconfig file?
I am trying to open Calculator from the iPad but is showing me Select a development team.

Appium version - 1.6.4
Xcode version - 8.3.2

Can anyone please help me?

Please find below the part of the error log.

> Signing for "WebDriverAgentRunner" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.
>   Code signing is required for product type 'UI Testing Bundle' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'
>   Signing for "WebDriverAgentRunner" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.
>   Code signing is required for product type 'UI Testing Bundle' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'
>   Signing for "WebDriverAgentRunner" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.
>   Code signing is required for product type 'UI Testing Bundle' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'
>   Code signing is required for product type 'UI Testing Bundle' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'

**TEST BUILD FAILED**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, WebDriver agent needs to be provided with developement team and proper provisioning profile. Have a look at the answer in the below link.

[Unable to launch ipa file in IOS 10 real Device using appium 1.6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262570/unable-to-launch-ipa-file-in-ios-10-real-device-using-appium-1-6-0/40521535#40521535)

Comment: When I run above command in terminal , it says "No such file or directory
"

Comment: May be WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj project path got changed try to find the path and try again.